# How to set address to default

Tags: magento

I try to set address to default in /controllers/OnepageController.php :

```
     $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

     foreach ($customer->getAddresses() as $address){
            $addressType = $address->getCustom_address_type();
            if ($addressType == 'school'){
                Mage::log("SetAddressDefault", null, 'mygento.log');
                $address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                        ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
                        ->save;
            }
        }
```

I've checked in log, the condition is met. Why do setDefaultBilling method not execute?

I use magento 1.7. Thanks.

Comment: don't you need () on Save... ->save();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change the

```
->save;
```

to

```
->save();
```